# Using matplotlib to obtain an overlaid histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, kaggle

I am new to python and I'm trying to plot an overlaid histogram for a manipulated data set from `Kaggle`. I tried doing it with `matplotlib`. This is a dataset that shows the history of gun violence in USA in recent years. I have selected only few columns for `EDA`.

```
 import pandas as pd

 data_set = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R related 
 Topics/Assignment/Assignment_day2/04 Assignment/GunViolence.csv")
 state_wise_crime = data_set[['date', 'state', 'n_killed', 'n_injured']]

 date_value = pd.to_datetime(state_wise_crime['date'])

 import datetime

 state_wise_crime['Month']= date_value.dt.month
 state_wise_crime.drop('date', axis = 1)

 no_of_killed = state_wise_crime.groupby(['state','Year']) 
 ['n_killed','n_injured'].sum()

 no_of_killed = state_wise_crime.groupby(['state','Year'] 
 ['n_killed','n_injured'].sum()
```

[I want an overlaid histogram that shows the no. of people killed and no.of people injured with the different states on the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0wSI.png)

Comment: Plese edit your question and add more information

Comment: Perhaps what you want is bar charts (x axis: year, y axis: sum of each segment)? I ask because histogram is to show the observed count (y axis) of x axis to understand the distribution of x-axis metric but in your case the summary stats are already calculated.

Comment: @gyoza Could you suggest the appropriate graph to use for displaying the no. of people killed(y-axis) to the different states in order to compare the varying amount of gun violence, state-wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! From next time, please post your data like in below format (not a link or an image) to make us easier to work on the problem. Also, if you ask about a graph output, showing the contents of desired graph (even with hand drawing) would be very helpful :)

---

`df`

```
    state   Year    n_killed    n_injured
0   Alabama 2013    9           3
1   Alabama 2014    591         325
2   Alabama 2015    562         385
3   Alabama 2016    761         488
4   Alabama 2017    856         544
5   Alabama 2018    219         135
6   Alaska  2014    49          29
7   Alaska  2015    84          70
8   Alaska  2016    103         88
9   Alaska  2017    70          69
```

As I commented in your original post, a bar plot would be more appropriate than histogram in this case since your purpose appears to be visualizing the summary statistics (sum) of each year with state-wise comparison. As far as I know, the easiest option is to use [Seaborn](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn). It depends on how you want to show the data, but below is one example. The code is as simple as below.

```
import seaborn as sns    
sns.barplot(x='Year', y='n_killed', hue='state', data=df)
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps.